# Handlers inside views, What are they for?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I frequently use Handlers to post delayed threads, schedule for UI Thread, etc.

Imagine Activity A1 with views mV1, mV2 and a Thread:

```
class A1 extends Activity {

     LightView mV1;
     UltraComplexView mV2;
     Handler mHandler;

     private Runnable oneSecondTimerRunnable() {
          Log.d(TAG, "One second more");

          mHandler.postDelayed(oneSecondTimerRunnable, INTERVAL); // 1st way
          mV1.postDelayed(oneSecondTimerRunnable, INTERVAL);      // 2nd way
          mV2.postDelayed(oneSecondTimerRunnable, INTERVAL);      // 3rd way
     }
}
```

Questions:

- Does every view have its own independent handler? Are they related? Can one handler be overloaded while another is free (example: LightView<>ultraComplexView)
- Does it make sense then to use a view's handler to postDelay stuff not really related to the view just because that handler is available to you at the moment instead of creating your own handler for handling your business?

I ask because Handler seems a pretty complicated class, tightly related to system threads, loopers, etc.. so if some of them are already instanced why not use them?

Answer (score 0):

i frequently use a Handler in a Activity to override handleMessage which is far better than using Runnables and from my observations c.a. 95% people use that nasty Runnables

Comment: yep messages are a cool thing, i use them sometimes, but runnables have their use too!